# Create colormap from dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

Am using `geopandas` to plot a map with categorical colors. `geopandas` is an interface to `matplotlib` so the same structures should work. What I'm after is to have each `key` display in a specific color. Random color from a predefined cm is fine, as long as the `No data` can be made grey.

```
keys = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'No data']
color_range = list(np.linspace(0, 1, len(keys), endpoint=False))
colors = [plt.cm.Pastel1(x) for x in color_range]
color_dict = dict(zip(keys, colors))
color_dict['No data'] = 'lightgrey'
```

The dictionary I get from this looks correct:

```
{'A': (0.98, 0.70, 0.68, 1.0), 
'B': (0.70, 0.80, 0.89, 1.0), 
'C': (0.87, 0.79, 0.89, 1.0), 
'D': (1.0, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0), 
'No data': 'lightgrey'}
```

When I try to convert it to a colormap, I get a KeyError: 0

```
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', color_dict)
```

My final plot command is:

```
merged_df.plot(column='GROUP', categorical=True, legend=True, cmap=cmap)
```

Comment: LinearSegmentedColormap isn't the function you think it is. Maybe try ListedColormap ?

Comment: Thanks @JohanC. I tried that, but ListedColormap doesn't accept keys for each color. I basically want to map a key in each record to a color

Comment: Well, LinearSegmentedColormap absolutely doesn't do that. I think you need to map your keys to numbers 0..4 and then use something like ListedColormap.  Possibly you'ld need to create an additional column in the dataframe with just these numbers (or even directly the colors).

Comment: @JohanC is right, the best way is to assign colors to each row and then use that row.

Comment: Yup, that seems the most likely best approach. Thanks for this folks. I'll put something together and post an answer when I get a chance. Thx